# nested loops involving conditions in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a piece of code

```
List<Obj1> result = new ArrayList<Obj1>();
for (Obj1 one : list1) {
            for (Obj2 two : list2) {
                if (one.getStatus() == two) {
                    result.add(one);
                }
            }
        }
```

In Java 8 Using streams I could write like this

```
 list1.stream().forEach(one -> {
        if (list2.stream().anyMatch(two -> one.getStatus() == two)) {
            result.add(one);
        }            
    });
```

can this be much simplified.

Comment: These two code fragments are not doing the same. The second is like having a `break` after `add` in the first one.

Comment: Why use streams if your old code just works? Streams is like any new, shiny functionality f: using f for the sake of using f is not the way to use f; do this and you're f.

Comment: @fge - Because streams give you free parallel processing.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon _iif_ no intermediate/terminal operation destroys that parallelism; and there is no guarantee _at all_ that any `Stream` is parallel to begin with

Comment: @fge: in this case, thinking about a stream way of doing it helped understanding that the inner loop is unnecessary, even without streams.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that `list2` contains unique values and you can use `equals` instead of `==` for `Obj2`, you can write it like this:

```
List<Obj1> result = list1.stream()
                         .filter(one -> list2.contains(one.getStatus()))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Though it would be more performant to put the `list2` elements to the `Set`.